# Upgrading to Rails 3: Problem with routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a problem to upgrade my routes.rb file.

I converted this route:

```
 map.resource :index,    :controller => "users", :action => "index"
```

By

```
resource :index, :to => "users#index"
```

There is no error raised but the page does not display correctly.
Does anyone have an idea?

#### Update:

I have this instruction:

```
resources :users
```

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
JNetExams::Application.routes.draw do |map|
    match 'login', :to => 'user_sessions#new', :as => 'login'
    match 'logout', :to => 'user_sessions#destroy', :as => 'logout'
    root :to => 'user_sessions#new'

    resources :groups
    resources :students
    resources :users
    resources :responses

    #map.resource :index,    :controller => "users", :action => "index"
    resource :index, :to => "users#index"
    map.resource :account,  :controller => "users"
    #resource :account, :controller => "users"
    resource :user_session
    resource :student
    resource :user
    map.resource :professor, :controller => "professors", :action => "index"
    #resource :professor, :to => "professors#index"

    map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
    #match ':controller/:action/:id'
    map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
    #match ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

    #map.connect '*url', :controller => :users, :action => :index
    match '*url', :to => "users#index"

    #map.connect '/user_sessions/show', :controller => "user_sessions", :action => "show"
    match '/user_sessions/show', :to => "user_sessions#show"
```

How can I upgrade this routes file to Rails 3?

Comment: What do you mean it 'does not display correctly'? Are you not getting the page at all or is there just a problem with the page?

Comment: Hi thx for your response. The page aren't correctly displayed. Some elements are not loaded.

Comment: ok then. why have `resource :index`, the `users#index` is covered by `resources :users`? Anyway, I think you mislead me with the routes, a lot of thing are different from rails 2.x to 3. What kind of elements are not loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resources :index` provides paths for an index resource. So `new_index_path` will point to the `new` action in the `IndexController`. If you do not have an index resource, you should not be using resources to define a path to `"users#index"`. This path is already given to you as `users_path` through `resources :users`. If you are looking to set an index page for your application, you can achieve that using `root :to => "users#index"`.

The problem of things *not displaying correctly* is vague and I employ you to throw more light on that. We are here to help after all.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a resource called index?

This looks more like it should be

```
resources :users
```

If you need more help, please show the whole routes file.